How to correctly implement the Celery Chain
Need to combine one audio track with several videos, currently there is a problem that the audio track is loaded several times.
t1 = download_video.si(url=video1)
t2 = download_video.si(url=video2)
t3 = download_audio.si(url=audio1)

d1 = group(t1, t3) | merge_video_and_audio.s()
d2 = group(t2, t3) | merge_video_and_audio.s()

finish = group(d1,d2) | send_report.s()
finish.apply_async()

in the current example, task3 will be launched 2 times, but I need it to be executed only 1 time. How can this be implemented?

Clarify the logic, when what should be run how? Just seeing some code which expresses the wrong logic isn't quite sufficient to understand how it should work.

I added details

Would it work to run t3 first, and then two groups [t1, merge] and [t2, merge] ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
